# Episerver PageStoreService, page properties not falling back to master language

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, episerver

I am using `PageStoreService` to pull down content from Episerver for some custom `PageTypes` that contain content in both English and German.

So for every English page that I pull down via `PageStoreService.getPage()`, I then call `PageStoreService.getLanguageBranches()` for that page id, and proceed to parse the page properties from the German page.

I am having trouble with property values falling back to the English version when no translation exists on the German page.

For example I have a property `EMAIL_ADDRESS`, and in the  CMS Admin mode I configure this page property to `'Inherits value'` and I also deselect `'Unique value per language'`. In CMS Edit mode I then enter an email address on the English page only, and this email address displays on the German page as greyed out non-editable. All good so far.

The problem is that when I pull down the German version of the page via `PageStoreService.getLangaugeBranches()`, the `EMAIL_ADDRESS` page property has no value.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the language fallback behaviour in EPiServer:

http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2011/3/Changes-to-the-EPiServer-CMS-Globalization/